# Get songs off of Windows iPod and onto a Mac

Tags: windows-xp, osx-snow-leopard, ipod

I have been using iTunes on a Dell running Windows XP to sync about 60 gigs of songs with my old school iPod. Well, the Dell's hard drive died the other day, and the only place that I have my music is on the iPod (I do have the CDs, but *really* don't want to have to re-rip 60 gigs of music).

So, now I have a shiny new MacBook Pro.  Is there a way to get my songs off of my iPod and onto the MacBook?  I googled, and found Senuti.  But, I'm leery of accidentally formating the iPod and losing my songs, and I can't tell if it is Snow Leopard compatible yet.

Has anyone recently gone through this process?  Please provide suggestions for copying songs from an iPod formated to work with Windows onto a MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard.

Thanks!

Comment: Senuti works in Snow Leopard (at least my .50.5 version does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ars Technica has a whole [guide](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/11/music-library-disaster-rip-songs-from-your-ipod.ars) on this. They recommend [PodWorks](http://www.scifihifi.com/podworks/) for OS X, [iRip](http://thelittleappfactory.com/irip/) for Windows and [gtkpod](http://www.gtkpod.org/about.html) for Linux.

Comment: Podworks is grand.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to mount the iPod as a usb drive and in the hidden iPod_Control\Music folder.  All of your files are there, but the file names are monged. You can copy the files off of the iPod onto a drive.  If you have iTunes you can "Add Folder to Library" and iTunes should reorganize them.  It probably won't fix the file names, but file names don't really mean anything in iTunes as long as the metadata is stil intact, which it should be.

Hope that helps.

Comment: well, there's also a handful of tools that let you set filename based off tags - mp3tag is an example for windows- but i'm sure there's a mac equivilent, assuming you want to unmong it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Yamipod](http://www.yamipod.com/main/modules/home/) in the past with success. It runs on Windows, OS X, and Linux and can even be setup to run directly off the iPod. It allows you to play and manage the songs on your iPod which includes copying songs off of the iPod and onto your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [PodsBlitz](http://dietrich.cx/Development/PodsBlitz) in the past, and I have sung its virtues for years now. It is written in Java and I have tested it personally on Linux and Windows, but I know that it also runs under MacOS without a glitch.

It is safe, very fast and very simple to install: just dump a .jar file in the root of your iPod. Double-click on its icon, choose the songs you want to copy and a destination folder, and voila: instant backup.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the program [SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/) to pull them off the iPod onto another Windows machine. Then import those songs into your Mac's iTunes. Once you're sure all your music is there, you can let your Mac format and sync your iPod.