# Extract 100G of Music from Ipod to Harddisk

Tags: ipod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get songs off of Windows iPod and onto a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/49705/get-songs-off-of-windows-ipod-and-onto-a-mac)

Hi,

I have an ipod 5th gen with 110G of Music and a macbook with itunes. I would like to rip all music files from my ipod to my hard disk and then select only some of the files and add them to the itunes library, which will sync with the ipod. I tried Expod and similar softwares but they hang with more than 50G. Do you know any other approach?

Thanks

Comment: G = 1 gravitational constant. GB = Gigabyte.

Comment: @MarkM: i have some music that's so bada** you'll feel like you're under 110G when listening to it.