# Extract music from old iPod to computer

Tags: itunes, ipod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get songs off of Windows iPod and onto a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/49705/get-songs-off-of-windows-ipod-and-onto-a-mac)

I have a lot of music on an old iPod, but if I connect it to my iTunes and sync it, it would delete all the songs on the iPod, right?

I was wondering if there is any way of extracting all the songs from my iPod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of solutions for this, programs like "[SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com/)", "[CopyTrans](http://www.copytrans.net/)", and "[MediaMoney](http://www.mediamonkey.com/)" are some of them (all free!).

I personally prefer **SharePod**. Very easy to use, just enough functions to solve the problem. You ca even *import* songs from Ipod to iTunes!

[image]