# F00 Music Tags to respective name, album, and artist

Tags: windows, linux, conversion, ipod-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get songs off of Windows iPod and onto a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/49705/get-songs-off-of-windows-ipod-and-onto-a-mac)

I'm looking for a program that will take all of my f00 files (extracted off of my iPod) and will convert their names, and put them into folders in respect to album and artist. So I was wondering if anyone you knew any programs like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, all those file have valid mp3/aac tags.

iTunes -
iTunes can actually do all you wanted - you import them, the consolidate the database, checking the option to copy the file into your itunes music folder. Then those files are then put into folders [artist name][album name][track no.][track name].[ext] automagically.

Foobar2000 - 
The included file operations component has such feature. Try it. It is a considerable upgrade from the old masstagger component.

Comment: sweet, i actually use foobar as a replacement for itunes, i didnt know it did that though, thank you